# Uploading Videos using the PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, http-post, facebook-php-sdk

I see here that you can now upload videos:
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/515/#video_upload

But I don't see any mention of it in the PHP SDK on github, or any examples... Is it not added there yet? Or is there anyway to do it using the PHP SDK, as opposed to throwing it up there using curl?

Thanks!

Comment: +1 to this. It seems such an obvious omission, but surely you can do `$facebook->api('/me/videos', 'POST', array('file' => "@$pathToVideo"));` ?

Answer (score -1):

Jason,

Make sure, if you are using the sdk, to `$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);` and then can post to the api:

```
try {
    $data = $facebook->api('/me/videos', 'post', $args); 
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo "result=ERROR&message=".$e->getMessage();
                die();
}
```